# Unable to protect a range based on day of week using google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google sheets I'm attempting to make a script to lock a range based on the day of the week for 12 hours when it is then unlocked. 
The idea is that users will not be able to edit the column on the day that it represents, but a select few admins are permitted.

The issue I'm running into is that range.protect doesnt seem to be considered a function and my editors dont get permission, only I do.
I've attempted to follow this template by google https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection 
to little success.

```
  var meeditor = "me@gmail.com"
  var myeditors = ["editor@gmail.com", "editor@gmail.com", "editor@gmail.com" "editor@gmail.com"]
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sign ups");
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getDay();
  if (n == 1)  {  //monday
    var range = ['C5:C20'];
    var rangesToUnProtect = ['B5:B20'];
    }
  if (n == 2) { //tuesday
    var range = ['D5:D20'];
    var rangesToUnProtect = ['C5:C20'];
  }
  if (n == 3) {  //wednesday
    var range = ['E5:E20'];
    var rangesToUnProtect = ['D5:D20'];
  }
  if (n == 4) {  //thursday
    var range = ['F5:F20'];
    var rangesToUnProtect = ['E5:E20'];
  }
  if (n == 5) {  //friday
    var range = ['G5:G20'];
    var rangesToUnProtect = ['F5:F20'];
  }
  if (n == 6) {   //saturday
    var range = ['H5:H20'];
    var rangesToUnProtect = ['G5:G20'];
  }
  if (n == 0) {  //sunday
    var range = ['B5:B20'];
    var rangesToUnProtect = ['H5:H20'];
  }
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription('no more signing up');

  protection.addEditor(meeditor) //keep myself editor
  protection.addEditors(myeditors)

  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());  /remove permissions from all others
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    for (var i = 0; i < rangesToUnProtect.length; i++) {  \\remove the protection the next day
  var protection = protections[i];
  if (protection.canEdit()) {
    protection.remove();
  }

}
}
}
```

I'm rather new at this and I' sure im not doing this optimally. How do I define this correctly? It's reminiscent of this bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148894990 but that was supposed to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the below error is due to the fact that you are **not declaring a range as a range but as a string** and the `protect` method is a method specific to a `Range Class` object or `Sheet Class` object, not applicable to a `string` object.

> TypeError: range.protect is not a function

In order to get **a range** you should change all your `var range` variables from this:

```
var range = ['RANGE1'];
var rangesToUnProtect = ['RANGE2'];
```

to this:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("RANGE1");
var rangesToUnProtect = sheet.getRange("RANGE2");
```

**Reference**

- [Sheet Class Apps Script - getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation);
- [Range Class Apps Script - protect()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect()).